# Why my query for pagination is slow?

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination

Below is the code I used for pagination. But it takes the same amount of time as it would when accessing all the records of the table inspite of selecting only a few records. What do I need to do to make it faster?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `random_procedure`(random params,in page_no int,in per_page int,out total_records int)  
BEGIN  
    set @statement := concat(@statement,'limit ',page_no*per_page-per_page,',',per_page);   //@statement is the statement selecting records i need to display

    PREPARE stmt FROM @statement;  
    EXECUTE stmt;  
    select FOUND_rows() into total_records;  

END
```

Comment: Please add your original statement

Comment: its too long and won't help to answer the question better anyway.

Comment: How many datasets do you want to select per page?

Comment: it would be variable and will be specified in the call statement for the procedure in the order start_page_no, no_of_records_per_page, and finally output the total_records.
e.g. call random_procedure(random params,5,10,@total_records) should give records from 41-50.  
select @total_records would give the total records.

Comment: whats the amount of data stored in the table? Which amounts did you compare (page -> whole amount)?

Comment: If you use `FOUND_rows()` (correctly), mysql will have to examine the whole query as if there was no `limit`. That's the whole point of `FOUND_rows()` - how else should mysql know how many rows there would be without `limit` than to execute the statement without `limit`. It will just not return all rows (you might save some time on data transfer there). And additionally, some (or rather: most) querys will not profit from `limit` at all, but that is probably not the main point here.

Comment: so can you tell me any other efficient way of finding the total number of records(around 500 records with 20 field values)?